# Vim color scheme not always working

Tags: linux, vim, colors

I have changed my color scheme in vim by adding this line to .vimrc:

`colorscheme desert`

When I open `.vimrc` or `.profile` the text is colored, but when I do for example `vim test.txt` the text I enter is not colored. Only the text mode is colored "INSERT/COMMAND".

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.txt` file is a plain text file, so it should not be colored. To color text you need a color scheme, and rules on how to color the file (so about syntax).

For `.vimrc` and `.profile`, vim can interfere the syntax from the standard file names. Vim can also interfere the syntax with the suffix or the first (or last) line in the file. You can force a syntax with `:set syntax=html`.